# Built in function for bag of visual words encoding in python

Tags: python, image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision, svm

In `matlab` I have this function

```
 function psi = encodeImage(encoder, im)
```

This function takes

- `im` which is list of names of images
- `encoder` which is `bovw.mat` I have this file as encoder

This function does bag of visual words encoding and returns the spatial histograms of images.

I use this histograms for training in SVM classifier.

I am doing this task in python and I don't want to implement the bag of visual words encoding as my main task is to implement SVM. Is there a built in function in python that does bag of visual words encoding and returns spatial histograms so I can train SVM classifier on histograms.

Comment: Have a look at this ``http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13628670/how-can-i-work-with-my-own-dataset-in-scikit-learn-for-computer-vision``

Answer (score -1):

Are you doing something similar to this?

http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/practicals/category-recognition/index.html

There is a computer vision library called Vlfeat. It's Matlab version is in active development state. However there exists a [Python interface](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyvlfeat/) as well.
Supports all major image processing features:

- Scale-Invariant Feature Transform (SIFT)
- Dense SIFT (DSIFT)
- Integer k-means (IKM)
- Hierarchical Integer k-means (HIKM)
- Maximally Stable Extremal Regions (MSER)
- Quick shift image segmentation

I am not sure whether Pyvlfeat will be sufficient or not. In fact, I was trying to do the same. Couldn't figure out. If it works, awesome, mention the trick in comment. If you have figured out some other method, please mention that too.